# Pyglet can read mp3 files in a Python Mac application (.app) created with PyInstaller, but only when I run the application from the command line

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, mp3, pyglet

I am creating [a program](https://github.com/benfertig/timestamper) using *Python* 3.10.8 (*Miniconda* distribution) that relies on *pyglet* version 1.5.27. One feature of my program involves loading audio files into *pyglet* using this function:

```py
pyglet.media.load("{path_to_audio_file}")
```

Recently, I packaged the source code for my program into both a *Windows* executable (.exe) and a *Mac* application (.app) using *PyInstaller* (although I used *Auto Py to Exe* for the *Windows* version).

This is the *PyInstaller* command I used to build the *Mac* version of my program (replace {path_to_repository} with the location of the repository on the local machine):

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "{path_to_repository}/setup_files/mac/file_icon_mac.icns" --add-data "{path_to_repository}/src/classes:classes/" --add-data "{path_to_repository}/src/images:images/" --add-data "{path_to_repository}/messages:messages/"  "{path_to_repository}/src/Time Stamper.py"
```

The *Windows* command that *Auto Py to Exe* generates looks exactly the same as the above command except that...

- the path to the *Windows* icon (.ico) file is provided instead of the path to the *Mac* icon (.icns) file

  **AND**
- all colons (":") are replaced with semicolons (";").

I am able to load and play mp3 files with *pyglet* just fine on the *Windows* version of my program as well as on the *Mac* version of my program, **but**:

- *pyglet* cannot load mp3 files on the *Mac* version of my program when I launch the application (.app) by double-clicking on it.
- *pyglet* will only load my mp3 files on the *Mac* version of my program when I either...

  - launch my *Mac* application (.app) by right-clicking on it and then selecting "Show Package Contents" and navigating to "Contents" -> "MacOS" and then double-clicking on the Unix executable within that folder.

    **OR**
  - launch my *Mac* application (.app) by entering the command:

    ```
    open -n {path_to_my_app} --args -AppCommandLineArg
    ```
- When I try to launch the *Mac* application (.app) of my program by simply double clicking on the .app file, I get the following error message:

  ```
  {Traceback (most recent call last):
  } {  File "pyglet/media/codecs/wave.py", line 58, in __init__
  } {  File "wave.py", line 509, in open
  } {  File "wave.py", line 163, in __init__
  } {  File "wave.py", line 130, in initfp
  } {wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id
  } {
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  } {Traceback (most recent call last):
  } {  File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
  } {  File "classes/macros/macros_buttons_file.py", line 107, in button_audio_select_macro
      self.parent.validate_audio_player()
  } {  File "classes/macros/macros.py", line 229, in validate_audio_player
      verify_audio_file(self.widgets["entry_audio_path"].get(), self.time_stamper)
  } {  File "classes/macros/macros_helper_methods.py", line 225, in verify_audio_file
      time_stamper.audio_source = load(file_full_path)
  } {  File "pyglet/media/__init__.py", line 142, in load
  } {  File "pyglet/media/__init__.py", line 132, in load
  } {  File "pyglet/media/codecs/wave.py", line 105, in decode
  } {  File "pyglet/media/codecs/wave.py", line 60, in __init__
  } {pyglet.media.codecs.wave.WAVEDecodeException: file does not start with RIFF id
  }
  ```
- Also, these are the warnings that were generated by *PyInstaller*, which *PyInstaller* placed in "build/Time Stamper/warn-Time Stamper.txt" ("Time Stamper" is the name of my application):

  ```
  This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
  necessarily mean this module is required for running your program. Python and
  Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional modules. For
  example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
  'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

  Types if import:
  * top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
  * conditional: imported within an if-statement
  * delayed: imported within a function
  * optional: imported within a try-except-statement

  IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
              tracking down the missing module yourself. Thanks!

  missing module named pep517 - imported by importlib.metadata (delayed)
  missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
  missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional)
  missing module named winreg - imported by importlib._bootstrap_external (conditional), mimetypes (optional), urllib.request (delayed, conditional, optional), platform (delayed, optional)
  missing module named nt - imported by os (delayed, conditional, optional), ntpath (optional), shutil (conditional), importlib._bootstrap_external (conditional), ctypes (delayed, conditional)
  missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional)
  excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional)
  missing module named _winapi - imported by encodings (delayed, conditional, optional), ntpath (optional), subprocess (optional), mimetypes (optional)
  missing module named msvcrt - imported by subprocess (optional), getpass (optional), pyglet.extlibs.png (delayed, conditional)
  missing module named pyogg - imported by pyglet.media.codecs.pyogg (top-level)
  missing module named PIL - imported by pyglet.image.codecs.pil (optional)
  missing module named Image - imported by pyglet.image.codecs.pil (optional)
  missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
  missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
  missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
  missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
  missing module named pyglet.window.BaseWindow - imported by pyglet.window (top-level), pyglet.window.headless (top-level), pyglet.window.cocoa (top-level), pyglet.window.win32 (top-level), pyglet.window.xlib (top-level)
  missing module named 'gi.repository' - imported by pyglet.media.codecs.gstreamer (optional)
  missing module named gi - imported by pyglet.media.codecs.gstreamer (optional)
  ```

I know that *pyglet* works better with wav files, but I find it strange that *pyglet* could read my mp3 files in every case except for this very specific case on my *Mac*, so if possible, I would really like to get it to work there too. Also, I am running *macOS Catalina* 10.15.7 on an 11-inch, Mid 2012 *MacBook Air* with a 1.7 GHz Dual-Core *Intel* Core i5 processor.

**Update:**

I have been experimenting with this more and I believe I have identified the problem. To read mp3 files, *pyglet* requires *ffmpeg*. When I installed *pyglet* using the following command, the *ffmpeg* dependency was automatically installed to my computer:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyglet
```

**When I simply run my *Mac* application (.app) from the command line:**

- My application (.app) defaults to my system's default *Python* interpreter (i.e., my base *miniconda* environment), and so my application has all of the *Python* packages I have installed using "conda/pip install" commands at its disposal.

  - This means that, when I run my application (.app) from the command line, my computer is able to find both *pyglet* as well as the *ffmpeg* dependency that was installed alongside *pyglet* (allowing for my application to read mp3 files).

**However, when I run my *Mac* application by double-clicking on the application (.app) generated by *PyInstaller*:**

- My computer relies **only** on packages that were included in the *PyInstaller* application (.app) bundle.

  - Since *PyInstaller* seems to detect that *pyglet* is necessary for my application (.app) to run, it includes *pyglet* in the final application (.app) bundle, so I would have suspected *PyInstaller* to automatically include *ffmpeg* in this application (.app) bundle as well (since *ffmpeg* was automatically installed alongside *pyglet* as a dependency when I ran the aforementioned "conda install" command). **However**, this does **not** appear to be the case.

I am almost **certain** that *PyInstaller* is not including *ffmpeg* in my *Mac* application (.app) because, while I was debugging my code, I found that the following statement...

```
pyglet.media.have_ffmpeg()
```

evaluated to **True** when I ran my application (.app) from the command line, but evaluated to **False** when I double-clicked on the application (.app) generated by *PyInstaller*.

So now, I am trying to figure out how to make *PyInstaller* include *ffmpeg* in my *Mac* application (.app) in such a way that *pyglet* can detect that *ffmpeg* is there (which, I believe, would allow *pyglet* to make use of *ffmpeg* to be able to read mp3 files), but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to do this.

To try and make *PyInstaller* include *ffmpeg* in my *Mac* application (.app), I have tried adding different permutations of the following arguments to my *pyinstaller* command:

```
--add-binary "/opt/miniconda3/bin/ffmpeg:bin/"
```

```
--add-binary "/opt/miniconda3/bin/ffmpeg:ffmpeg/"
```

```
--add-data "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ffmpeg"
```

```
--collect-all pyglet
```

```
--collect-all ffmpeg
```

```
--collect-all ffmpeg-python
```

None of these arguments, when added, seemed to make it so that *PyInstaller* included *ffmpeg* in my application (.app), or at least, if *ffmpeg* was included (and I don't think it was but I'm not sure), then these arguments did not allow *pyglet* to detect it.

Also, those last two arguments get ignored completely by *PyInstaller* as it says that there are no packages with either the name *ffmpeg* or *ffmpeg-python*. I even installed standalone *ffmpeg* packages with *conda* using the following commands (and then tried running the *PyInstaller* command again):

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg-python
```

Installing these packages and then running *PyInstaller* again yielded the same problem (i.e., *PyInstaller* did not detect any packages with the name *ffmpeg* or *ffmpeg-python*, and so those packages were ignored and not included in the .app bundle).

So, based on my complete understanding of my problem thus far, it seems that I need to find a way to properly package *ffmpeg* into my application (.app) in such a way that *pyglet* can communicate with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, Mac doesn't support MP3 by default in Pyglet (this will be added in an upcoming 2.x version and possibly backported to 1.5) and requires FFmpeg.

Pyglet looks for the dylib files for ffmpeg in the `os.environ["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"]`. You could also play around with `pyglet.options["search_local_libs"] = True` which will search a folder called `lib` in your script directory for these lib files.

Here is some info on ffmpeg installation: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/media.html#ffmpeg-installation

Comment: Thank you! This worked. For anyone reading this, what I did was, in my code, before calling "pyglet.media.load('{path_to_audio_file}')", I added the following statement: "pyglet.options['search_local_libs'] = True". Then, I downloaded the 7z of ffmpeg for Macs (version 5.1.2 to be exact, but the current latest version should always work) from the following page: https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/. Then, I extracted the ffmpeg executable from the 7z file and added the following argument to my PyInstaller command: "--add-binary {path_to_ffmpeg_executable}:lib/". My program can now read mp3 files.